# Data not removed until page refresh

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I have a function that removes data from a table (and of course corresponding database), however, when I click the remove-button, it doesn't remove the data from the table (it does get removed from the database though).

If I then refresh the page (not with ctrl+r, because it'll ask me for form resubmission), it is gone.

This seems to be some sort of caching, and I am wondering if there is some kind of workaround, like reloading the page after a few seconds. I have tried the header()-function from PHP, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<input type=hidden name="member_email" value="<? echo $member['email']; ?>"/>
    <?php
        $email = $member['email']; 
        if(isset($_POST['fjern_kursist'])) {
            /*delete participant from db*/
            $delete_query = "DELETE from ";
            $delete_query .= $wpdb->prefix . "member_data ";
            $delete_query .= "WHERE email = '" . $_POST['member_email'] . "' AND course_id = '" . get_the_ID() . "'";
            $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( $delete_query ));
            header( "refresh:5;url=http://kursus.billetten.dk" );
        }?>
</td>
```

I use Google as just a placeholder, in the perfect situation I go to the current page/URL.
What am I doing wrong in my header? I have also tried the following header, but that doesn't work either:

```
header( "refresh:5;url=http://google.com" );
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: The complete table:

```
if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) { ?>
    <h3>Deltagere</h3>          
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Fornavn</th>
                <th>Efternavn</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Virksomhed</th>
                <th>Fjern</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
<?php if ($members_array){
    foreach ($members_array as $member) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $member['firstname'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $member['lastname'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $member['email'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $member['company'] ?></td>
            <form id="cancel_form_admin" method="POST" action="">
                <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="fjern_kursist"/>
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                </button>
                <input type=hidden name="member_email" value="<? echo $member['email']; ?>"/>
    <?php
        $email = $member['email']; 
        if(isset($_POST['fjern_kursist'])) {
            /*delete participant from db*/
            $delete_query = "DELETE from ";
            $delete_query .= $wpdb->prefix . "member_data ";
            $delete_query .= "WHERE email = '" . $_POST['member_email'] . "' AND course_id = '" . get_the_ID() . "'";
            $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( $delete_query ));
            header( "refresh:5;url=http://kursus.billetten.dk" );
        }
    ?>
            </td>
        </form>
    </tr>
<?php }
  } ?>
```

Comment: check your input field name in the form is `fjern_kursist` or not?

Comment: `input` doesn't have an attribute `action`. So this is a full page reload when you POST? No Ajax or anything? Can you show how you get the content? Also `$member['email']` should be `$_POST['member_email']`

Comment: I have just added more of my code.

Comment: where hae you put the code to display the table?is it after the code you have shown or before it?

Comment: I have just added more of the code.

Comment: Good god man. You generate the html table, then you delete the rows. Do it the other way round.

Comment: Does the `header(" refresh:5;....");` actually happen? And is it after that ok?

Comment: No, the header doesn't happen. That's also the whole question, as I figured that might be what I need :) @RiggsFolly Please elaborate?

Comment: Your HTML is also invalid, your `<form>...</form>` should be within the `<td>...</td>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you send the DELETE query after the SELECT query. Can't you just put the `if(isset($_POST` somewere in a header / model (not such a big WP user)? That way the user should be removed before the SELECT is done from the database, stored in a variable etc.

Comment: Worth a try! I'll get back on this.

Comment: So simple, yet so useful. Thanks! Quite new to PHP, so didn't think about the fact that the select query would run before it would delete.

Answer (score 2):

Code runs from top to bottom.

So your code generates the html for the page, and then checks if there is anything to delete.

So when there is something to delete it does the delete after you have already built the page using the undeleted data.

```
// First check for deletes

$email = $member['email']; 
if(isset($_POST['fjern_kursist'])) {
    /*delete participant from db*/
    $delete_query = "DELETE from ";
    $delete_query .= $wpdb->prefix . "member_data ";
    $delete_query .= "WHERE email = '" . $_POST['member_email'] . "' AND course_id = '" . get_the_ID() . "'";
    $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( $delete_query ));
}

// Now run the unshown code that loads $members_array from the database


// now run the html page building that used $members_array 
// that is created from any remaining member on the database
```

Answer (score -2):

The table might be populated from the $_POST rather than from the database maybe? - Or how do you populate the members-array?

You must refresh what is populating your table with the corresponding info from the database  - that is nothing if youare deleting everything.

Comment: No its not, see the question.

Comment: That does not make sense. The only thing I send with $_POST is the email.

Comment: This is not an answer its a comment, Please use comment and not an answer for this.

Comment: It might have been an answer. Not all answers are correct , it's not a comment.

Comment: It was based on the question without the added code.

Comment: How do you populate the members array?

Comment: Also - I can't comment yet it seems. Technically impossible.

Comment: You need 50+ reputation I believe.

Comment: You are clearly not getting the question: I had a table with content, which would be removed from the database by clicking the remove-icon. However, after the automatic page refresh it would still be in the table, so I had to do a manual refresh to see it removed. Check the accepted answer for what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Well, he achieves exactly what I said - you must populate the members array with the right data. what he said achieves exactly that. I can't guess the whole code you have there. he apparently guessed right.